# Kendo UI Upload - Synchronous mode, show group selection as separate files

Tags: file-upload, kendo-ui

I'm using the Kendo UI Upload Control and wanted to allow for multiple files in synchronous mode, but when adding multiple files at the same time, they are grouped together in the same line item.  Is there a way to have each separate file as its own line item when group selecting?  In the screenshot that is linked, there are 2 line items, but I would like to have 3 line items; One for each file

Javascript:

```
$('#files').kendoUpload({
    localization: {
        select: 'Select files to upload<br />-or-<br />Drag files here to upload'
        },
    multiple: true,
    showFileList: true,
    success: function (e)
    {
    },
    select: function (e)
    {
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="/Api/UploadUrl" style="width:100%">
    <div>
        <input name="files" id="files" type="file" />
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="k-button" /></p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Screenshot of the grouping: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVoK4.png

Answer (score 0):

The files cannot be listed in different list items. The synchronous Upload widget does not differ from a regular `<input type="file" />` element with the [multiple attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/multiple) applied, which means that all files are added to the [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) of the current input.